# jquery ajax post request to flask error, but works perfectly with get request why? EDIT: failed to load response data

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to send the user's message to the server side. I keep getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
> it is logging upon error function
> {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm very new to AJAX.

```html
<form id="user_form" action="" method="POST">
  <textarea id="the-message" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="send_button" name="send_button" value='message_sent'>Send Message</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#user_form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#the-message').val()) {
    user_message = $('#the-message').val();
  }
  var url_link = window.location.href;

  $.ajax({
    data: {
      user_message
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: url_link,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Bad request: " + error);
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: So I tried switching to a get request and that works but post request doesn't can someone please explain why? and tell me how to make it work with post

I look into the chrome network tab to debug and it says failed to load response data. Anyone know how to fix this?

when I switch it to get it sends the whole html file not the data. How do i fix this?

The issue was on the serverside

Comment: url_link =  window.location.href; How come ?

Comment: so in my flask I have a layout that takes user form. This way I don't have to manually copy and paste the layout on all my html file. Since it's in layout there is no route url. so the post request is being sent to the page the user is on. Thus, idk what the url it is. It depends on what the user is on

Comment: can you try to specify the url in the action attribute of form tag

Comment: I did try that, but same error

Comment: for some reason when i switch it to a get request it works but post doesn;t

Comment: @dragonn: Don't edit your question to put "solved", instead, write a detailed answer, and [accept it](/help/accepted-answer). Remember that [so] is not a forum!

Answer (score 0):

Hi so the issue was coming from the server side. I forgot to jsonify the return values upon returning values.